# Apache Spark Receiver Scheduling

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark

I have implemented a receiver that is supposed to connect to a WebSocket stream and get the messages for processing. Here is the implementation that I have done so far:

```
class WebSocketReader (wsConfig: WebSocketConfig, stringMessageHandler: String => Option[String],
  storageLevel: StorageLevel) extends Receiver[String] (storageLevel) {

  // TODO: avoid using a var
  private var wsClient: WebSocketClient = _

  def sendRequest(isRequest: Boolean, msgCount: Int) = {
    while (isRequest) {
      wsClient.send(msgCount.toString)
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
  }

  // TODO: avoid using Synchronization...
  private def connect(): Unit = {
    Try {
      wsClient = createWsClient
    } match {
      case Success(_) =>
        wsClient.connect().map {
          case result if result.isSuccess =>
            sendRequest(true, 10)
          case _ =>
            connect()
        }
      case Failure(ex) =>
        // TODO: how to signal a failure so that it is tried the next time....
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
  }

  def onStart(): Unit = {
    new Thread(getClass.getSimpleName) {
      override def run() { connect() }
    }.start()
  }

  override def onStop(): Unit =
    if (wsClient != null) wsClient.disconnect()

  private def createWsClient = {
    new DefaultHookupClient(new HookupClientConfig(new URI(wsConfig.wsUrl))) {
      override def receive: Receive = {
        case Disconnected(_) =>
          // TODO: use Logging framework, try reconnecting....
          println(s"the web socket is disconnected")
        case TextMessage(message) =>
          stringMessageHandler(message).foreach(store)
        case JsonMessage(jsValue) =>
          stringMessageHandler(jsValue.toString).foreach(store)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How is this Receiver being run? Does this Receiver run on the worker nodes or on the driver node? Is this way of sleeping a thread a correct approach?

The reason why I want to do this is that the server that is exposing the WebSocket end point would need a count on the messages that I want to receive. Say if I ask the server for 100 messages, it would give me 100 messages and so on. So I need a way to periodically schedule this request to the server. Currently, I'm using the Thread.sleep mechanism. Is this advisable? What could be the alternative?